# PHP add key data to json

Tags: php, json

Have a nice day. I have created the following basics:

```
{
    "1111": {
        "h264": {
            "url": "TEST",
            "expire": 1649453177
        }
    }
}
```

I need to add the following lines to the same key:

```
{
    "1111": {
        "h264": {
            "url": "TEST",
            "expire": 1649453177
        },
        "h265": {
            "url": "TEST",
            "expire": 1649456380
        }
    }
}
```

But whatever I try, it does this to me:

```
{
    "1111": {
        "h264": {
            "url": "TEST",
            "expire": 1649453177
        },
        "0": {
            "h265": {
                "url": "TEST",
                "expire": 1649456380
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is some sample code:

```
$time = time();
$codec = "h265";
$url = "TEST";
$id = "1111";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('./data.json'), true);
$post_data = array($codec => array('url' => $last_line,'expire' => $time));
array_push($data[$id], $post_data);
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
file_put_contents('./data.json', $data);
```

Can someone advise me not to add the 0 key to me there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
$post_data = array($codec => array('url' => $last_line,'expire' => $time));
array_push($data[$id], $post_data);
```

To:

```
$post_data = array($codec => array('url' => $last_line,'expire' => $time));
$data[$id]['h265'] = $post_data;
```

Comment: Thank you. it wasn't quite right but I already managed and this is the right solution.
$post_data = array('url' => $last_line,'expire' => $time);
$data[$id][$codec] = $post_data;